# App_Offline.htm content works but no content is displayed

Tags: app-offline.htm

I'm having an unexpected behavior with my app_offline.htm on a hosted 4.0 pipelined Web Application site. I keep the file in the root directory under an alternate spelling and then rename it to app_offline.htm when I need it. It works as expected to take my site offline. However, the content (3k bytes) of the app_offline.htm file is never served. Instead, I see a text/plain string 'The service is not available.' While this sort of gets the job done, my custom file displays a message in English and Spanish, and so my custom app_offline.htm display is what I want. This plain text appears in all browsers tested. The method displays the file's content on my development server IIS 7.5 Windows 7.

I've tried working with the tech folks at the hosting service that hosts the site, but they haven't figured this one out. Since the text output is not on my site files, I presume it is served by the host. Is there something in machine.config that might determine how the app_offline.htm works on their server setup?

Bob

Answer (score 1):

We had a similar issue.  We had a health check page that our load balancer would ping and if that page did not return what was expected, it would take that server offline.  Well, if you have the app_offline.htm page, the health check page would not return what was expected, and all of the servers would be taken offline, resulting in the same message you received.  We just had to disable the health check during mx.